# How to understand the relationships between "distance" methods of the Web Audio API panner node

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm currently trying to understand and get a better mental image of the relationship between the following methods

```
listener.setPosition(x,y,z);
panner.setPosition(x,y,z);
```

From here on out I will describe what I think I know and hopefully a few people will tell me where I'm wrong and correct me.

Now at its most basic I imagine a sphere with both of these "positions" occupying the same place in the middle. In a way you could look at the panner.setPosition and listener.setPosition() as both physical "things" inside our hypothetical sphere.

Now when you change the coordinates of one you move it in relation to the other.

So one point of confusion is this. From what I've come to understand the coordinates of these two methods are not any particular value, however unlike the x value where 1 and -1 determine the range with 0 in the middle,  the z index actually does seem to have a value, so if I give it a positive value it does "push the sound further away" (or more to the point - attenuate it). 0 is close and 200 is far for example. What value is this ?

**Partial Answer:**

The reason 1 to -1 are hard right/left is because the z is set to zero hence there is 0 space between the listener and the "sound source" which is represented by the panner node. I am still unclear as to what "value" the z index is.

**The other questions I have:**

**1.**

If you have a hypothetical "world" where an imaginary person is moving closer or further away from a sound source, should you program the listeners z coordinate or should you program the panners z coordinate. The reason I'm asking this is because [in this example](http://mdn.github.io/panner-node/) the panner is programmed and the listener stays in the same place but the UI suggest the listener is moving toward the sound source. I guess this question is more about best practice as it seems either will work.

**2.**
When I run any sound through the default panner node it literally sounds different ( more muffled and "dense", almost as if two instances of the same audio file are playing simultaneously or the highs are getting cancelled out). I assume since this is the case there is some culmination of "settings" that the programmer is expected to know about to remedy this. I'm interested in knowing whatever *that* is.

If you would like a side by side example below are two JSfiddle examples. One uses a panner node and one does not. open both of them and play the files side by side while listening in headphones, the difference is subtle but noticeable.

[JSfiddle with panner node](http://jsfiddle.net/X38pk/17/)

[JSfiddle without panner node](http://jsfiddle.net/X38pk/13/)

Answer (score 1):

> 0 is close and 200 is far for example. What value is this?

I think the numbers are arbitrary units. The section on [distanceModel](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#idl-def-DistanceModelType) gives the formulae for calculating the change in gain based on the distance between the source and the listener.

Also the spec mentions that "PannerNode scales/multiplies the input audio signal by distanceGain"

For answers to your question:

**Q1. -   should you program the listeners z coordinate or should you program the panners z coordinate**

It really depends on your application. The API is designed to have a single `Listener` per `AudioContext`. But you can create multiple AudioSources with a PannerNode attached to each of them. You can envision this as a bunch of Loudspeakers (AudioSources) that you can position in 3D space, but you yourself (Listener) can also move around. In such a case depending on whether you want the sources to move with respect to each other or not, you may or may not want the listener to move.

**Q2. - sounds different ( more muffled and "dense")**

<s>I am not sure about this. I have not encountered this before. Could you give an example/demo?</s>

Based on [trying the various panning models](http://jsfiddle.net/notthetup/X38pk/16/), it seems like the muffled audio is the result of using the `HRTF` panning model. The HRTF Impulse Responses definitely do NOT have flat frequency response and will colour the audio. You can use a `equalpower` panning model instead.

Be warned though a lot of these things are gonna change in the upcoming change of WebAudio. You can read more about it here https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/372

Comment: I edited my post with two JSfiddles to compare the same sound with and without a panner node

Comment: @TaoistWA I think the links are wrong. The one you mention with Panner node seems to be with a filter

Comment: I forked your JSFiddle with the correct changes. http://jsfiddle.net/notthetup/X38pk/15/

Comment: Added with with different panning models. http://jsfiddle.net/notthetup/X38pk/16/

Comment: I modified it, I had to remind myself of the mediaElementSource method and was looking at another JsFiddle....I accidentally copied the wrong one over

Comment: @TaoistWA Updated my answer as to why it sounds different.

Comment: It seems like the changes you mentioned in the link will still require an understanding of the things I mentioned. They might make the default equalpower or make things a bit easier to get started with but the points I brought uup are still going to be relevant